# Django and ajax - data returning value but not populating field

Tags: django, ajax

I am new to Django and Ajax. I have a dropdown that is populated from a database. I want another field to populate based on the selection made in the dropdown. I am getting the return value, but it is not populating the form field. Console.log shows the value being returned. It just never shows on the form field and I am sure the field name is correct. In the browser I get 600. How do I get the 600 into the #id_Deductable field? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`

```
<form method="POST" id="BaseQuoteForm" data-agent-url="{% url 'ajax-load-agent' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Add">
            </form>

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <script>
                $("#id_Agency").change(function () {
                var url = $("#BaseQuoteForm").attr("data-agent-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
                var Agency = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

                $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                    url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
                    data: {
                    'Agency_id': Agency       // add the country id to the GET parameters
                    },
                    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#id_Agent").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
                 }
                });

                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $("#id_Primary_Plan").change(function () {
                var url = $("#BaseQuoteForm").attr("data-agent-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
                var PlanData = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

                $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                    url: url,                   // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
                    data: {
                    'PlanData_id': PlanData       // add the country id to the GET parameters
                    },
                    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#id_Deductable").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
                    
                }
                });

                });
            </script>
```

`

Comment: Can you add your html with the element of id `id_Deductable`.

Comment: It is done using crispy form. The first ajax call works and populates the form field, but the second ajax call does not. The first is a string and second is a number. Thank you for looking at it!